# How can i create a List that the items inside will be random tree of websites addresses?

Tags: c#, arrays

What i mean is that the List will be in the end with an offline websites addresses but as a tree.
For example the program will create automatic List of websites addresses for example the first one will be:

```
http://www.aaa.com
```

The next website will be:

```
http://www.bbb.com
```

The idea is that the program will create automatic websites addresses and that each next web sites will be the next level of the web sites above in hte List.

```
If the user type : http://www.aaa.com
The next site will be http://www.bbb.com
So aaa.com is level 0 and bbb.com is level 1
http://www.ccc.com will be level 2
```

And after that i want to add another randon that each level will be random number of sites.
For example :

```
Level 0 http://www.aaa.com
Level 1 http://www.bbb.com http://www.bb1.com http://www.bb2.com
Level 2 http://www.ccc.con http://www.cc1.com
```

The link in level 0 is the one the user entered so it will be allways one link in level 0.
The other levels can have more then one site each time.

So the List in the end will be in index [0] http://www.aaa.com

```
index [1] will have more 3 indexs each one a site address.
index [2] will have more 2 indexs with two sites.
```

What i want to do in general is to be able to use this sites addresses offline.
So maybe not random maybe the user just a click a button and it will create all the time the same List the user will be able to set only how many levels to create. And the only random thing will be how many sites will be in each level.

---

This is for a web crawling program i have and i want to use it even of there is no internet connection for some reason so i can still working on the program and check things.
Now today if there is no internet connection i cant test the program.

Thats why i wanted to create somehow automatic List of websites when im in off line mode.

Hopw can i do it ?

Comment: If  the first site is `http://www.aaa.com` ,  Why is the next site `http://www.bbb.com` instead of `http://www.aab.com` or `http://www.aba.com` or `http://www.baa.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it sounds like you want a jagged array. This is easy. You can create a `List<List<string>>` for example:

```
List<List<string>> myList = new List<List<string>>();
myList.Add(new List<string>());
myList[0].Add("http://www.aaa.com");
myList.Add(new List<string>());
myList[1].Add("http://www.bbb.com");
myList[1].Add("http://www.bb1.com");
// and so on...

Console.WriteLine(myList[0][0]);   // displays http://www.aaa.com
Console.WriteLine(myList[1][0]);   // displays http://www.bbb.com
Console.WriteLine(myList[1][1]);   // displays http://www.bb1.com
```